# Eliminate array rows having DUPLICATE PAIRS of elements

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider an array whose rows hold **pairs** of elements.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,  3,4,  5,6,  7,8],
              [1,2,  3,4,  1,2,  3,4],
              [4,5,  5,4,  6,7,  5,6],
              [6,7,  8,9,  8,9,  0,1],
              [4,5,  4,5,  4,5,  4,5],
              [3,5,  5,3,  2,5,  3,5]])
```

How can I eliminate, from array `a`, any row that has **a DUPLICATE PAIR?** (duplicate pairs have the same elements in the same order).
In this example, the output would be:

```
d = [[1,2,  3,4,  5,6,  7,8],
     [4,5,  5,4,  6,7,  5,6]]
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far? It would be helpful to see your current progress.

Comment: I've been using code like shown below.  The problem is speed.  Also,
it can get quite cumbersome when there are, say, 4 or 5 pairs, not just 3.

mask = ((a[:,0] == a[:,2]) & (a[:,1] == a[:,3])) | \
       ((a[:,2] == a[:,4]) & (a[:,3] == a[:,5])) | \
       ((a[:,0] == a[:,4]) & (a[:,1] == a[:,5]))

has_pair_DUPES = a[mask]
has_UNIQUE_pairs = a[~mask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the array in your question is just formatted using spaces to show the pairs. First reshaping your numpy array so the pairs are together would be helpful.

Then you can use `np.unique` with an `axis` argument to determine if there are duplicate pairs in each row.

Here is some example code that would accomplish it:

```py
import numpy as np

# put pairs together assuming a.shape[1] is even
A = a.reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1] // 2, 2)

# iterate over rows of a and see if there are duplicate pairs
# checks that number of unique pairs == number of original pairs
# and creates a boolean mask of which rows to keep
mask = [np.unique(A[i], axis=0).shape[0] == A[i].shape[0] for i in range(len(A))]

# apply boolean mask to get rows without duplicate pairs
without_duplicate_pair_rows = a[mask]
```

Comment: That does the trick! I had an error in the mask statement.